# errors upon apache jexl upgrade from 3.2.1 to 3.3

Tags: jexl

i have upgraded from apache jexl 3.2.1 to 3.3 and suddenly my test cases fail

on jexl 3.3  this test case works but only after reverting to 3.2.1 behaviour

```
  @Test
    public void testUsingWhiteSandbox() {
        // given
        JexlSandbox sandbox = new JexlSandbox(false);
        sandbox.allow(System.class.getName()).execute("currentTimeMillis");
        sandbox.allow(AtomicLong.class.getName()).execute("set");

        Map<String, Object> namespaces = new HashMap<>();
        namespaces.put("sns", System.class);

        JexlEngine jexl = new JexlBuilder()
                .sandbox(sandbox)
                .namespaces(namespaces)
                .strict(true)
                .silent(false)
                **.permissions(JexlPermissions.UNRESTRICTED)**
                .create();

        AtomicLong atomicLong = new AtomicLong();
        MapContext context = new MapContext();
        context.set("result", atomicLong);

        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

        //when
        jexl.createScript("result.set(sns:currentTimeMillis())").execute(context);

        // then
        AtomicLong result = (AtomicLong) context.get("result");
        assertThat(result.get()).isGreaterThanOrEqualTo(now);
    }
```

but if i comment out the line **".permissions(JexlPermissions.UNRESTRICTED)"** which i had to add to revert to 3.2.1 behaviour, the test case fails.
how do i get this to work without having to use the 3.2.1 behaviour which is **less secure**

your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your test - at least -, you are in a very secure sandbox since the only allowed methods are System::currentTimeMillis and AtomicLong::set.
The 3.3 restricted set precludes using the System class and permissions are applied before sandboxes, thus your test failure.
An easy fix would be to use:

```
JexlPermissions permissions = new JexlPermissions.ClassPermissions(System.class);
```

Which will use the restricted set as a base augmented with the classes you allow as arguments, in this case re-allowing System as a class through permissions, the sandbox still only allowing currentTimeMillis as callable method.

If I may, I'd probably avoid exposing System however - belt and suspenders - and would  probably create a dedicated class for the 'sns' namespace to only expose what is necessary (permissions and sandbox being tailored accordingly). Something like:

```
   public static class SnsNamespace {
    public long currentTimeMillis() { return System.currentTimeMillis(); }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much @henrib , the insight on interplay of class permissions and sandbox permission is very useful. I appreciate your help.